# Why has my ArcGIS Enterprise username changed case?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal

Something rather peculiar has occurred on our federated, on premesis ArcGIS Enterprise instance.

Last week I had logged in with my username which is case sensitive containing caps and lower case letters as a named user. This week that username does not work unless I only use lower case letters.

From what I've read so far, you cannot change your username- but mine has changed and I'm curious as to why/how it happened. Also it seems to have only affected me and the change has been carried through to groups and content so that the lower case version of me still owns everything Mr uppercase did and is still owner and member of the appropriate groups.

I'm concerned that this is a symptom of some deeper problem with the server. On the face of it the server logs don't show anything useful (no warnings) but I will need to do a deep dive to see if anything crops up. Has anybody had a similar experience?

Comment: Check to see what type of identity store your Portal installation is using.  For example, where I work ours identity store is based on Windows Active Directory, and is administered by our IT group.  If you have a similar setup, I suppose it's possible your IT group changed username formatting recently.